# Laravel - sessionId changes inside controller after ajax call from axios

Tags: laravel

When I retrieve my sessionId from view like this `$session_id = Session::getId();` it works and the id does not change. 
However when making API calls to api route to a controller, it returns a different `$session_id` everytime.  
How can I keep get the sessionId that is called from my view?
I suspect middleware has something to do with it.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class MyController extends Controller
{
  public function sample(Request $request){
    $session_id = \Session::getId();
    return $session_id; 
  }

}
```

my route:

```
Route::middleware('api')->post('/test', function (Request $request) {
    $aa = new MyController();
    $session_id = Session::getId();
    $obj = $aa->mymethod($request, $session_id);
    return $obj;
});
```

Comment: @Berto99 but I am calling for sessionId from laravel's controller. Why would axios get involved with that?

Comment: try to add `Route::get('test', function(){return session()->getId();});` to your route file and check if it changes

Comment: @Berto99 no that has the same result, everytime `session()->getId();` gets called it becomes a new string.

Comment: @Berto99 my route looks like this `Route::middleware('api')->post('/test', function (Request $request) {
    $aa = new MyController();
    $session_id = Session::getId();
    $obj = $aa->mymethod($request, $session_id);
    return $obj;
});`

Comment: API DOES NOT HAVE SESSION

Comment: @Berto99 thank you, what would be the best way then, not use api and use web route?

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve